# Does elastic search use previous search frequencies?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

Does elastic search utilize the frequency of a previously searched document. For example there are document A and document B. Both have similar score in terms of edit distances and other metrics however document A is very frequently searched and B is not. Will elastic search score A better than B. If not, how to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch does not change score based on previous searches in its default scoring algorithm.  In fact, this is really a question about [Lucene scoring](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/scoring.html), since Elasticsearch uses it for all of the actual Search logic.

I think you may be looking at this from the wrong viewpoint.  Users search with a query, and Elasticsearch recommends documents.  You have no way of knowing if the document it recommended was valid or not just based on the search.  I think your question should really be, **"How can I tune Search relevance in an intelligent way based on user data?"**.

Now, there are a number of ways you can achieve this, but they require you to gather user data and build the model yourself.  So unfortunately, there is no easy way.

However, I would recommend taking a look at https://www.elastic.co/app-search/, which offers a managed solution with lots of custom relevant tuning which may save you lots of time depending on your use case.